# how to select a folder for downloading file in sdcard

Tags: android, filesystems, android-sdcard

In my app, I need to download a file from the server to sdcard.But here before download I need to select the folder(any folder) in sdcard where the file should download.So how to select the folder in sdcard?

Comment: @WarrenFaith agree with you, why should i waste my time.

Comment: You can always try doing a [search on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+select+file) or a [search on Google](https://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=select+file+android&pbx=1&oq=select+file+android&aq=f&aqi=g1g-b3&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=574l2741l0l3721l19l13l0l1l1l0l446l2438l0.9.3.0.1l14l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=a1bc1589ec616832&biw=1680&bih=925).

Answer (score -3):

this is how i save my pic in SD card.

```
OutputStream stream = null;
File tmpFile = creatTempFile();

try {
    stream = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
yourImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, stream);


private File creatTempFile(){
    final File path = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "folder_name" );
    if(!path.exists()){
        path.mkdirs();
    }
    return new File(path, "file_name");
}
```

sorry,yesterday I want to copy my codes to here,but copy the worry codes,this is right.

Comment: -1 for undocumented, unexplained code-only answer... and missing formatting

Comment: sorry,I'm not good at English.But I really had saved images in the SD card by this. @WarrenFaith